# Can we use other names for the AJAX Control Toolkit classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, type-alias

I am using the AJAX Control Toolkit in an ASP.NET web site. I would like to change the names used to refer to the toolkit's classes according to my project's conventions, both in the Controls pane and in the markup itself.

Maybe something like:

```
 <%@ Register ?something? TagPrefix="MyControls" %>
```

For instance, I'd like to rename the `AutoCompleteExtender` class as `SelectTextBox` in the code, so I can use it like this:

```
 <MyControls:SelectTextBox ID="sss" runat="server" ColumnList="aaa"
     ColumnType="0" ColumnWidth="300" DataField="aaa"
     DetailedSearch="1" FillQuery="SELECT XXX" ValueField="EmployeeID" />
```

Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

I was curious about your question (that's why I edited it in the first place), so I looked around, and I'm afraid I'm not coming back with good news.

Although facilities like [type aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765.aspx) do exist in C#, they will only affect the modules where the `using` directives are in effect, and will not propagate to the ASP.NET markup AFAICT (let alone to the Controls pane).

Barring extending Visual Studio itself, your best bet may actually be to derive your own classes from the ones in the toolkit, use these in your code, and create a custom Controls pane section out of them. That way, naming will be consistent everywhere in your environment.

On a more positive note, maybe someday you will want your `SelectTextBox` control to do *something more* than a plain `AutoCompleteExtender`, and then you will have the derived class already there waiting for you.

Comment: another reason to not use this "toolkit" :)

Comment: @Liam, well, that's a dual client/server-side toolkit, so it can only use Javascript's aliasing capabilities halfway :)